# socket.io function returns before the callback finishes - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

In socket.io function I'm creating new user in DB and returns inserted id back. But my function is returns before the database callback finishes. So I'm getting the inserted Id back in client side:

```
  io.on('connection',function (socket) {
    socket.on('newUser',function (user) {
        io.emit('newUser',createChatRoom(con,user.email,user.phone));
    });

  });
```

**My create user function:**

```
var createChatRoom = function (con, email, phone) {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE `email`='" + email + "'", function (error, result) {
        if (error) throw error;
        if (result.length == 0) {
            var chatToken = require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(email).digest("hex");
            con.query("INSERT INTO user(email,chat_token,phone) VALUES('" + email + "','" + chatToken + "','" + phone + "')", function (error1, result1) {
                return result1.insertId;
            });
        } else {
           return "Old User";
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Provide callback to createChatRoom funtion, and call it from the result of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered some asynchronous JavaScript!

The calls you're making to your database with `con.query` don't actually finish immediately like you think they will since they are what we call "non-blocking".

A network request is "non-blocking" and can take some unknown amount of time to complete. If it was a "blocking" operation your program would sit around waiting for the response from the database. You can't block execution in JavaScript because everything runs in one big loop behind the scenes.

To solve this, we use callback functions to make requests "non-blocking". You're actually already using them! The idea is we pass a `function` as an argument to an operation that we know will take some time to complete. When the potentially long running operation finishes, it calls your callback function with the result.

In your code, after your `query` runs, the supplied callback function is called.

```
con.query("INSERT INTO user(email,chat_token,phone) VALUES('" + email + "','" + chatToken + "','" + phone + "')", function (error1, result1) {
```

The solution to your particular problem is to make your `createChatRoom` function take a callback as an argument.

```
io.on('connection',function (socket) {
  socket.on('newUser',function (user) {
    createChatRoom(con, user.email, user.phone, function (error, result1) {
      if (error) {
        // hanlde your error
        // return
      }
      io.emit('newUser', result1);
    })
  });
});

var createChatRoom = function (con, email, phone, callback) {
  con.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE `email`='" + email + "'", function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }
    if (result.length == 0) {
      var chatToken = require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(email).digest("hex");
      con.query("INSERT INTO user(email,chat_token,phone) VALUES('" + email + "','" + chatToken + "','" + phone + "')", function (error1, result1) {
        if (error1) {
          return callback(error1)
        }
        return callback(null, result1.insertId)
      });
    } else {
      return callback(null, "Old User");
    }
  });
};
```

You might need to change things a bit but hopefully you get the idea!

[Here's a talk](https://youtu.be/99GUhlv6kaY) I gave on the topic and a [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html).

Comment: I forgot to mention that we use a pattern known as "Error first" in the Node world for callbacks. What this means is that the first argument to a callback should be an error if there is one or `null`. You should always check for these errors similar to how I did.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Since io.emit just emit an event with a message, you could just call `createChatRoom` inside of socket on, and move the line of `io.emit` to the end of `createChatRoom`

```
io.on('connection',function (socket) {
    socket.on('newUser',function (user) {
        createChatRoom(con,user.email,user.phone)
    });
});


var createChatRoom = function (con, email, phone) {
con.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE `email`='" + email + "'", function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    if (result.length == 0) {
        var chatToken = require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(email).digest("hex");
        con.query("INSERT INTO user(email,chat_token,phone) VALUES('" + email + "','" + chatToken + "','" + phone + "')", function (error1, result1) {
            io.emit('newUser',result1.insertId);
        });
    } else {
       io.emit('newUser',"Old User");
    }
});
```

};

Comment: You can create the callback inside of `socket.on` callback, so you can access your variables

Comment: can u post the example code using above scenario ??

Comment: I think that last edit is what you are looking for. I haven't work a lot with socket.io but I always used `emit`to send values o data, without callbacks

Answer (score 0):

As Maria notes, your newUser handler include emit of `newUser` event. When you fire `newUser`, the handler takes over, so this code "cycles". Some refactoring has to be done. Meanwhile, calling `createChatRoom` is (normally) slow as it has I/O.

NodeJS is async by natrue. What I'd suggest is to sync, like

```
io.on('connection',function (socket) {
    socket.on('newUser',function (user) {
        setImmediate(() => {
            console.log('Do something (async)');
        });
        io.emit('newUser',createChatRoom(con,user.email,user.phone));
    });

  });
```

Note: setImmediate is not available in NodeJS < 0.9

Comment: my version is V6.9.2